# Get interval selection for a Vega-Altair plot published in streamlit

Tags: python, python-3.x, streamlit, altair, vega

How can I get the selected datapoints for a Vega-Altair plot publihsed using Streamlit?

I am defining the box selection for selecting datapoints, and it works well. However i am unable to get the selected datapoints for further processing.

```
  box_selection = alt.selection_interval(name="interval")
```

I can get the selected datapoints in jupiter notebooks by using jChart = alt.JupyterChart like described here https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/jupyter_chart.html#interval-selections and it work wonderfully. But my charts are published in streamlit and jChart = alt.JupyterChart does not seems to retain the chart state and is not doing the trick.

I am trying to use the session state to get chart state which I think is not correct as the state of the chart when updated will not be updated in session state, so need some bridge to cover this gap.

Any ideas?

Complete graph generation code below:

```
import altair as alt
import streamlit as st

def generate_chart(df,xcol,ycol,lbl='off',color='basic',title='', tooltip=['DataPoint','Ccontent']):
  
  legendSelection = alt.selection_point(fields=['Data'], bind='legend')
  zoompan = alt.selection_interval(bind='scales',
                                          # on="[mousedown[event.altKey], mouseup] > mousemove",
                                          translate="[mousedown[event.altKey], mouseup] > mousemove!",
                                          zoom="wheel![event.altKey]"
                                          )
  # Box selection for highlighting or filtering data points
  box_selection = alt.selection_interval(name="interval")
  
  chart = alt.Chart(df).mark_circle(size=150, stroke='#666', strokeWidth=0.8, opacity=1).encode(
    x=
    alt.X(xcol,
        scale=alt.Scale(zero=False),
        axis=alt.Axis(labels=False, ticks=False, domain=False)
    ),

    y=
    alt.Y(ycol,
        scale=alt.Scale(zero=False),
        axis=alt.Axis(labels=False, ticks=False, domain=False)
    ),

    color=alt.condition(box_selection, 'Data:N', alt.value('lightgray'),  # Update color based on selection
                          legend=alt.Legend(columns=1, symbolLimit=0, labelFontSize=14)),        
    tooltip=tooltip,
    opacity=alt.condition(legendSelection, alt.value(1), alt.value(0.2)),  # Use selection to control opacity
    ).add_params(
    box_selection, zoompan, legendSelection
    )
  
  if lbl == 'on':
    text = chart.mark_text(align='left', baseline='middle',dx=15, size=13,color='black').encode(text=tooltip[0], color= alt.value('black'))
  else:
    text = chart.mark_text(align='left', baseline='middle',dx=10).encode()

  result = (chart + text).configure(background="#FFFFFF"
        ).properties(
        # width=800,
        height=700,
        title=title
       ).configure_legend(
          orient='bottom',  
          labelLimit=0,
          titleFontSize=14,
          labelFontSize=14,
          symbolStrokeWidth=0.8
         )
  jchart = alt.JupyterChart(result)
  st.session_state["jchart"] = jchart # For getting selection of points, but does not look like this will work as the object will not get dynamically updated in session state.
  return result #.interactive()
```

Comment: JuptyerChart needs ipython/jupyter widgets to be supported, so maybe that is not the case with streamlit? You can find the latest on altair selections in streamlit here https://github.com/streamlit/streamlit/issues/2263 (notice the last comment)

Comment: Thanks @joelostblom. Seems like whenever a complete solution is available, plotly would be a good option to stick to. I tried the last comment but still no robust solution. I have upgraded my plots to plotly in anticipation that that forum is more active.

Comment: Based on what has been said in those two threads it seems like both Plotly and Altair will be supported with the same functionality so I think it is just up to you which library you prefer. Both are also already supported in other dashboard libraries such as Dash, Panel, and Solara, so that's another option if you are not tied to streamlit